# Setting the layout of the swiped card in RecyclerView using ItemTouchHelper

Tags: android, layout, swipe, android-recyclerview, recyclerview-layout

I created a `RecyclerView` and attached it to an `ItemTouchHelper`, so I can swipe the items in the list. 
The problem is, when I swipe an item, the separator (2dp high View) swipes with it - there seems to be an empty layout below my item.

Is there a way to change that layout? Or other ways to handle it?

Comment: @crtn Try use ItemDecoration for separators. see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.ItemDecoration.html